# How do I add a custom field type in a custom Module in SugarCrm 6.5

Tags: types, field, customization, textfield, sugarcrm

I'm adding a custom module in Module Builder in SugarCRM 6.5 . I can add fields either in the module builder or in the studio. But I need a special field that has some javascript and that auto-completes itself and other fields with data from a script( that I need to call with XMLHttpRequest ).

Currently I found no similar questions that are thoroughly answered anywhere else and so far, backwards engineering the code didn't yield any answers for me.

Comment: You'll be looking for a logichook here, or custom record changes, not a field change

Comment: Actually I think the best thing would be to make a custom SugarField type.     I'm currently trying to do something along the lines of this : https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2009/03/16/tip-new-tipsandtricks1-creating-a-youtube-sugar-field/

Answer (score 0):

create a file on this path 
"custom\Extension\modules\\Ext\Vardefs\fields.php"
you may change values according to your needs.

$dictionary['Module_NAME]['fields']['field_name'] = array(

```
    'required' => false,
    'name' => 'field_name',
    'vname' => 'LBL_field_name',
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'massupdate' => 0,
    'no_default' => false,
    'comments' => '',
    'help' => '',
    'importable' => 'true',
    'duplicate_merge' => 'disabled',
    'duplicate_merge_dom_value' => '0',
    'audited' => false,
    'reportable' => true,
    'unified_search' => false,
    'merge_filter' => 'disabled',
    'len' => '255',
    'size' => '20',`enter code here`
);
```

Once the file is in place, navigate to Admin >> Repair >> Quick Repair and Rebuild. It is also best practice to clear your browser cache before using the new field type in Studio.